# Finding and removing palindrome rows in 2D numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numba

What would be pythonic and effective way to find/remove palindrome rows from matrix. Though the title suggests matrix to be a *numpy ndarray*, it can be *pandas DataFrame* if it lead to more elegant solution.

Obvious way would be to implement this using for-loop, but I'm interested is there a more effective and succint way.

My first idea was to concatenate rows and rows-inverse, and then extract duplicates from concatenated matrix. But this list of duplicates will contain both initial row and its inverse. So to remove second instance of a palindrome I'd still have to do some for-looping.

My second idea was to somehow use broadcasting to get cartesian product of rows and apply my own ufunc (perhaps created using numba) to get 2D bool matrix. But I don't know how to create ufunc that would get matrix axis, instead of scalar.

EDIT:

I guess I should apologize for poorly formulated question (English is not my native language). I don't need to find out if any row itself is palindrome, but if there are pairs of rows within matrix that are palindromes.

Comment: What is the structure of your data? Can you add an example dataframe in your question with an expected result? What do you mean by palindrome rows? Normally palindrome would be used in the context of a word

Comment: @TomMcLean Input is any two dimensional array.  Two rows would be considered palindrome if inverse of the second row would be the same as the first row

Answer (score 3):

I simply check if the array is equal its reflection (around axis 1) in all elements, if true it is a palindrome (correct me if I am wrong). Then I index out the rows that aren't palindromes.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
    [1,0,0,1], # Palindrome
    [0,2,2,0], # Palindrome
    [1,2,3,4],
    [0,1,4,0],
])

wherepalindrome = (a == a[:,::-1]).all(1)
print(a[~wherepalindrome])
#[[1 2 3 4]
# [0 1 4 0]]
```

Answer (score 3):

[Naphat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67702881/2148416) is the pythonic (*numpythonic*) way to go. That should be the accepted answer.

But if your array is **really** large, you don't want to create a temporary copy, and you wish to explore Numba's intricacies, you can use something like this:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def palindromic_rows(a):
    rows, cols = a.shape
    palindromes = np.full(rows, True, dtype=nb.boolean)
    mid = cols // 2
    for r in nb.prange(rows):   # <-- parallel loop
        for c in range(mid):
            if a[r, c] != a[r, -c-1]:
                palindromes[r] = False
                break
    return palindromes
```

This contraption just replaces the elegant `(a == a[:,::-1]).all(axis=1)`, but it's almost an order of magnitude faster for very large arrays and it doesn't duplicate them.